# Leaflet как сохранять значения элементов при повторном сеансе

Tags: javascript

На карте Leaflet | Map data © OpenStreetMap  есть форма с инпутами

```
<form class="leaflet-control-layers-list"><div class="leaflet-control-layers-base"><div class="leaflet-control-layers-base">
<label><div>
0:<input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers" checked="checked">
</span></div>
<label><div>
1: <input class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" type="radio" name="leaflet-base-layers" checked="checked">
</span></div>
<label><div>
....n : <input class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" type="radio" name="leaflet-base-layers" checked="checked">
</span></div>
</div></form>
```

как при повторном посещении страницы получать карту с результатом выбранного чекбокса из предыдущего посещения (сеанса)

Вот код. не могу коррктно получить по условию из localStorage

```
var _rect = document.querySelector("form.leaflet-control-layers-list");



 _rect.addEventListener('click', clicker);

function clicker(e) {
  const parent = e.target.parentNode;

  window.new_rect  = {};




  parent.childNodes.forEach(elem => {
    if (elem.tagName == 'INPUT') window.new_rect[elem.className] = elem.innerHTML;
    if (elem.tagName == 'INPUT') window.new_rect[elem.className] = elem.checked;

    if (elem.checked == true)

            elem.setAttribute('id', 123);


// window.new_rect = JSON.stringify(elem.getAttribute('id'));

   localStorage.setItem('old_checked', window.new_rect);


  });


}


$(document).ready(function(e) {
document.querySelectorAll("input.leaflet-control-layers-selector").forEach((elem, indx) => {

     window.getNew_rect = localStorage.getItem('old_checked');
              if(window.getNew_rect) {
               window.getNew_rect = JSON.parse(window.getNew_rect); 





        }         

  });

});
```

Comment: если не используете БД - предлагаю localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Сохраняю, не получается получить необходимый выделенный чекбокс при повторном посещении .... выложил код сверху (правка)

Comment: Это помоему только через куки